# overlay-filesystem that can differentiate between metadata and file content?

Tags: aufs, overlayfs, union-mount, unionfs

AFAIK with [`aufs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs) when a file is `touch`ed (ie. only it's metadata changed, not it's contents), then the copy-on-write mechanism of the file system will copy the whole file into the r/w layer, essentially duplicating the file.

Say, I only want to change the **metadata** (modification time, permissions, owner, etc.) of a *lot* of files, is there some union-type file system (OverlayFS perhaps?) that only keeps track of the metadata changes, unless the file *content* is altered - resulting in much less duplication?

Or maybe some other trick can lead to the desired result?

Comment: well... btrfs does depending on how you configure the mirror. and anyway, a snapshot definitely would.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OverlayFS will do this when the "metadata only copy up" feature is enabled. This can be done when mounting by passing the *metacopy=on* mount option.

More details can be found in the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.14/filesystems/overlayfs.html#metadata-only-copy-up).